# I deleted `tracker-miner-fs` from Lubuntu because I thought it was a cryptominer! How can I reinstall it?

Tags: lubuntu

My CPU was at 100% usage and I thought that it was because of `tracker-miner-fs` mining for Etherium or something.

How can I install it again? I've been free of issues since I deleted it, but now I'm worried. Is it important? Is it actually a cryptominer?

Comment: I had no idea that `tracker-miner-fs` is installed on Lubuntu by default! I thought that it was a GNOME thing, since it provides the file indexing service for it. I also had a look at the [Lubuntu 22.04 manifest file](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04/release/lubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest) and it isn't listed there. Did you install a GNOME/GTK program that pulled it in as a dependency?

Comment: You haven't said what release; but it isn't installed by default, eg. I can't find it on https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/22.04.1/release/lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest so what are you using? (I looked at other releases too)

Answer (score 4):

The package is `tracker-miner-fs` and isn't required but can be easily reinstalled:

```
sudo apt install tracker-miner-fs
```

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu does not include the package `tracker-miner-fs` on it's ISOs, so **no it is not important** (to Lubuntu).

You didn't provide any release details, but a look at what is included can be achieved easily by looking at the manifest (ie. what's found on the ISO and thus what can be installed).

The latest Lubuntu manifest is here - https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/22.04.1/release/lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest

You'll find the same on [20.04.5](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/20.04.5/release/lubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.manifest) too (I can confirm @BeastofCaerbannog's comment), I even went back and looked in EOL 18.04.5's & it's not there.

FYI:  I booted a Lubuntu 20.04.5 install made during QA (*Quality Assurance testing*) last week; nothing found.  If I search on my own box it does exist; but that's because it's a *depends* rule for `nautilus`, and my *bloated* box does have installed `ubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop` & more installed - ie. my installation of Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) added it.

Comment: For answers, I like @ChanganAuto's ... but I've concentrated on the *Lubuntu* tag as we do not include the package.

Answer (score 1):

`tracker-miner-fs` is part of the indexing service Tracker on the Ubuntu desktop. On the default Ubuntu desktop, it cannot be removed without fully removing the Gnome Shell desktopenvironment, of which it is a hard dependency.

On a Lubuntu system, `tracker-miner-fs` is not installed by default. That you have it may have been because at one time you also had the standard Ubuntu desktop on that system.

It is not needed at all in Lubuntu, and you very likely are not using it at all, so feel comfortable leaving it out: your system is a little more clean now.